# Computability problems -- can't solve

Tags: computer-science, computability

I have a pair of exercises I can't solve (tomorrow I'll have a test).
I need some kind of solution so I can apply it to other exercises...thanks to all!

In the following $W_n$ means the domain of the function with code $n$.

1. Show that : given a recursively enumerable set $A$, there exists a $g$ total recursive such that: 
   $$W_{g(x)} = \begin{cases}
   \Bbb N,& x\in A\\
   \varnothing,& x\notin A.
   \end{cases}$$
2. Given:
   $$f(0)=n_0 \text{ and } f(n+1) = \varphi_n(n)f(n)$$

Show that $\mathrm{cod}(f)$ is recursive (with explanation)

3. Show that there does not exist a total recursive function $f$ such that:
   $$\text{for every }x, \text{ if } W_x \text{ is a recursive set then } W_{f(x)} = \overline{W_x} \text{ which is the complement of } W_x.$$

I'm a newbie of this community so I'm sorry if I wrote something bad...
thanks to all!!

Comment: I edited your question to make it more legible, but I wasn't familiar with some of your notation. Feel free to edit it if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Excuse me, what does $W(g)x$ mean?

Comment: If you want $\omega$, use \omega.

Comment: @Math1000, thanks soo much, now its really much more legible.

Comment: @user3491648

dom(φi) = Wi

Comment: Set of natural numbers..oh yeah thanks!!! i'll edit right now

Comment: I still don't know what $W(g)x$ is

Comment: And by $= !$ do you mean $\not =$ written \not =?

Comment: Edited..it was Wg(x), sorry...
By ! i mean "complement"...W with the line above the character

Comment: What is $W_g(x)$?

Comment: g is a function, so Wg(x) it's the domain of the function with index g(x)...its the domain of φg(x).

Comment: Use \bar {bla} for $\bar{bla}$ or \overline{bla} for $\overline{bla}$

Comment: Edited!! Thank you so much

Comment: For 1, $g(x)$ outputs the program which takes in $n$, tests whether $x \in A$, and if so outputs $n$. For 2, $\operatorname{cod}(f)$ is finite hence recursive. I don't understand what 3 is asking.

Comment: For 3, do you mean $\text{for every }x, \text{ if }W_x \text{ is a recursive set then } W_{f(x)} = \overline{W_x} \text{ which is the complement of } W_x$.

Comment: Yeah, that's the meaning of 3! Ok got it..forget about what i said about 1) :D

Comment: But i think i didnt understand the answer for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $g(x)$ outputs the program which takes $n$ as input, tests whether $x \in A$ and if so outputs $n$.
2. $\operatorname{cod}(f)$ is finite hence recursive. There is some $n$ for which $\phi_n(n)$ does not terminate, and hence for all subsequent $N > n$,  $f(N)$ does not terminate.
3. Such an $f$ would allow you to solve the halting problem. To test whether program $n$ terminates on $i$, run $\phi_n(i)$ in parallel with $\phi_{f(n)}(i)$; whichever one terminates tells you whether $i \in W_n$.

Comment: Only one question 
(for 1.):
You are basically crafting the function g to answer this question right?

Comment: @AlessandroMassa yes

Comment: @AlessandroMassa if anything is unclear, leave a comment

Comment: I think i didn't understand the answer for 3. Why it would allow to solve the halting problem? I thought we have to use 1. to deduce an answer by contraddiction...maybe i was wrong

Comment: @AlessandroMassa Because if $\phi_{f(n)}(i)$ terminates, then $i \not \in W_n$, and if $\phi_n(i)$ terminates then by definition $i \in W_n$. So by running both tests in parallel, one of them is guaranteed to terminate and tell you whether $\phi_n$ terminates on $i$.

Comment: So the function described in 3. can't exist because it can distinguish between a total function (it always terminates or not -- is a recursive set, finite set)...right?

Comment: @AlessandroMassa No. Deciding totality is stronger than deciding termination. The function in 3 lets you decide whether a function terminates on an input, and this is impossible.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit dumb but i can't see the link between

$$ W_{f(x)} = \overline{W_x}$$ 
and the test on the halting problem...

I'm feeling very dumb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24603/discussion-between-user3491648-and-alessandro-massa).

Comment: ok...im there!!...but can't see you

Comment: @AlessandroMassa Actually that was by accident. Please try to figure it out.